# sprite-kit: line drawing error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

Hi everyone I made an app in xcode 6 beta 3 using swift and sprite-kit and everything worked fine. The code is supposed to draw a smooth red line. Now I downloaded xcode 6 beta 4 and my code doesn't work properly, the problem I have is that my lines aren't smooth anymore and there are gaps in it. I have read apples release notes but I couldn't find anything that could explain why my code isn't working.

```
func drawLines() {
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, location.x, location.y)
    var locationX: CGFloat = location.x
    var locationY: CGFloat = location.y

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, self.frame.size.width/2, 100)
    drawLine.append(SKShapeNode())
    drawLine[index] = SKShapeNode()
    line.append(drawLine[index])
    line[index].path = path
    line[index].strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    line[index].fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    line[index].lineWidth = 5.0
    line[index].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointMake(512, 100),toPoint: CGPointMake(locationX ,locationY))
    line[index].physicsBody.dynamic = false
    line[index].zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(line[index])
    index++
}
```

Comment: You made absolutely no changes to the code between beta 3 and 4? If so, report it as a bug to Apple.

Comment: The only change I made was adding the fillColor method to see If it would change anything but it didn't, guess I'll report a bug than